# Can't decode text

Tags: c#, string, encoding

Example:

```
"Ð—Ð°Ð¿Ð¾Ð»Ð½Ð¸ Ð¿Ñ€Ð¾Ñ„Ð¸Ð»ÑŒ"
```

I try

```
var latinString = "Ð—Ð°Ð¿Ð¾Ð»Ð½Ð¸ Ð¿Ñ€Ð¾Ñ„Ð¸Ð»ÑŒ"; // år
Encoding latinEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
Encoding utf8Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("WINDOWS-1252");

byte[] latinBytes = latinEncoding.GetBytes(latinString);
byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.Convert(latinEncoding, utf8Encoding, latinBytes);

var utf8String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8Bytes);
```

but it doesn't work:

**�?аполни п�?о�?ил�?**

this is **russian text**, help plz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, `latinString` is **UTF-8** string in **Win-1252** encoding. Let's return it back into **UTF-8**:

```
  // Uncomment in case of .Net Core or .Net 5
  // Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);

  var latinString = "Ð—Ð°Ð¿Ð¾Ð»Ð½Ð¸ Ð¿Ñ€Ð¾Ñ„Ð¸Ð»ÑŒ"; 

  string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(
    Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(latinString));

  // Let's have a look
  Console.Write(result);
```

**Outcome:**

```
  Заполни профиль
```

Comment: but i can't parse this string "ÐÐ¾Ñ, ÑÑÐ¾ ÑÐµÐ±Ðµ Ð½ÑÐ¶Ð½Ð¾ ÑÐ´ÐµÐ»Ð°ÑÑ"